# PHP if else while (with mysql) statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have this piece of code in a function of mine that echos "Empty" if it cannot grab the data stored in the variable $result. The "Empty" part works fine. However, it will not echo the users data if the conditional enters the `else` part, why?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `earnings` DESC LIMIT ".$load.",1") or die (mysql_error());
if(!mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Empty";
} else {
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($name == true) {
            echo ucfirst($data['user']);
        } else {
            echo ucfirst($data['earnings']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `$name`? Also please remember that `mysql_*()` functions have been deprecated for years and are unsupported. Change your code!

Comment: @miken32 A variable in my function. (This code is part of my function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `mysql_fetch_row($result)` as a test, you are missing the first row of your data always. Check if number of rows is 0 instead.

Comment: PLEASE update your code to stop relying on functions that haven't been updated in years. You can probably update your code to use `mysqli_*()` in half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

HI I think you issue is in mysql_fetch_array(). This function will return array not associative array..

you can use

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `earnings` DESC LIMIT    ".$load.",1") or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   echo "Empty";
} else {
     while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH))
 {
    if($name == true) {
        echo ucfirst($data['user']);
    } else {
        echo ucfirst($data['earnings']);
    }
 }
}
```

Use mysql_num_rows intead of mysql_fetch_row to check empty recordset.

I pass the 2nd parameter in mysql_fetch_array which MYSQL_BOTH that will return both array and associative array..

Or you can use

mysql_fetch_assoc() function istead of mysql_fetch_array()..

Feel free to ask question..

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() returns both.

Comment: Mike you are right it return both but when you pass 2nd parameter MYSQL_BOTH as i right in my solution..

Comment: MYSQL_BOTH is the default setting.

Comment: @miken : i change the mysql_fetch_row to 
mysql_num_rows which will solve his problem..

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `earnings` DESC LIMIT ".$load.",1") or die (mysql_error());
    if(!$result) {
        echo "Empty";
    } else {
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            if($name == true) {
                echo ucfirst($data['user']);
            } else {
                echo ucfirst($data['earnings']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No explanation at all. No indications to what is changed or what was wrong. This is spoon-feeding.